# ASP.NET MVC WebApi post from controller fails after add SSL Cert

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, ssl, asp.net-web-api

I´ve a big problem. My MVC application had run good till i've add an SSL Certificate to my IIS Server.
The curious this is, that every action which comes from the client ui works great but i've an Controller method which post some important data to my WEB API and this doesn't run any longer.
I get the status code 401. The method send a delete before it post the data and this runs.

What could be wrong?

Here is my code:
Please feel free to ask my for further information.

```
                    HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
                    {
                        UseDefaultCredentials = true,
                    };

                    HttpClient clientt = new HttpClient(handler);

            Uri baseadress1 = new Uri(host + "/api/");

            HttpResponseMessage response = clientt.DeleteAsync(baseadress1 + "TVKurve").Result;

            HttpResponseMessage response2 = clientt.PostAsJsonAsync(baseadress1 + "TVKurve", info).Result;
```

This is the Exception which i get when i debug the code:

{"Error while copying content to a stream."}

Comment: Can you check if there are any inner exceptions?

Comment: that is the inner exception. I've try to switch the SLL Settings on the server from ignore to accept "Client certificates" an than i've got an 'Unauthorized'  the delete method is still working

Comment: What is "host" defined as?

Comment: As api Url `String host = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);` The Result is "https://  webserver"